# How can I get the absolute orientation value using deviceorientation event?

Tags: cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, w3c

The Cordova plugin deviceorientation is being deprecated and the w3c deviceorientation event is the reason for this.

However, I have yet to be able to get the w3c event to give me the absolute heading value (relative to north) for IOS.  I've read that the absolute functionality isn't supported in the event, so I'm at a loss what to do.

[To give context, this is for the compass page in an app I have developing for a few years now, and has been out on the market for almost as long. I'm having an issue with a user who has a Sony xz2 phone where the plugin doesn't seem to be reporting headings from the compass sensor, so I started the migration process to the w3c stuff.  Tech stack: javascript, phonegap/cordova, Adobe phonegap build]